# JAVA 6 and corrupted files after uploading using Apache FTPClient 3.1 and FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE

Tags: java, upload, ftp, apache-commons, ftp-client

I'm really going bonkers on this.

I'm writing a small Java (must be SDK 6) tool using the commons-net-3.1.jar library to upload a bunch of files to another bunch of servers simultaneously. I will use it with .jpg images mostly. I set the connection to BINARY_FILE_TYPE before anyone ask :)

When I try and run it, everything goes smooth but sometimes, after uploading the images, they have "small lines" on them, like if the file had been corrupted on its way.

This little piece of code is the one who does all the work. Any clues about how should I manage the first catches when the os.write fails in order to keep the file uploading right?

```
try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(rutaFichero);
    OutputStream os = ftp.storeFileStream(nombreFichero);
    byte buf[] = new byte[8192];
    bytesRead = is.read(buf);

    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        try {
            os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        }
    }

    is.close();
    try {
        os.close();
        completado = ftp.completePendingCommand();
        if (completado) {
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {}
}
```

Out of curiosity, I thought it could be just bad conditions on the line so I checked the sizes of files after transfering for some days and... none of them matched! WTF!?

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in the first line here:

```
bytesRead = is.read(buf);

while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
    try {
        os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    }
}
```

You never write the first `buf` contents. You just read them and then read subsequent chunk in `while` loop. Remove the first `is.read()` and you'll be fine.

It's another reason to avoid such tedious code and go for utility methods such as [`IOUtils.copy()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(rutaFichero);
OutputStream os = ftp.storeFileStream(nombreFichero);
IOUtils.copy(is, os);
is.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: I typed that line by mistake, wasn't in my code but thanks for pointing it. I changed to IOUtils.copy() and life was much easier, however, the problem wasn't solved at all until, some other fellow sent me an e-mail giving me an advice about being sure to set the mode type to binary AFTER login, never before and... wey-hey, it worked!

Thank you very much for your help Tomasz.
erm... how do I set this Question to Solved?

Comment: @gobispo: since my answer didn't really help you, I suggest you to change your comment to another answer and self accept it. Good luck!

Comment: Now I see. I'm really new to this and had no idea how to do it. Thanks again Tomasz and your answer, although not in the way I expected, did helped me to find an easier way to do things :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved when some fellow sent me an e-mail giving me an advice about being sure to set the mode type to binary AFTER login, never before.

Comment: Fixed my file corruption problem!